# How to import data into datagridview from .txt file

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have create a method that stores data from a datagridview into a .txt file. This runs when the application closes and works as I would like it too. I was wondering how I can then load this data back into the datagrid when the application loads again. This is the method that stores the data:

```
private void StoreData()
{
    var dataGrid = dataGridViewRegisteredVehicles;
    TextWriter writer = new StreamWriter(@"C:\DatagridStorage\Text.txt");
    for (int i = 0; i < dataGrid.Rows.Count; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < dataGrid.Columns.Count; j++)
        {
            writer.Write("\t" + dataGrid.Rows[i].Cells[j].Value.ToString() + "\t" + "|");
        }
        writer.WriteLine("");
        writer.WriteLine("-----------------------------------------------------");
    }
    writer.Close();
    MessageBox.Show("Data Exported");
}
```

Comment: If your datasource of your DGV is a datatable you can save the datatable as XML file in one instruction and then read the xml file in one instruction.

Answer (score 0):

Try this for ideas:

- Make a new form
- Put a datagridview on your form
- Put this code in the FormClosing event (double click FormClosing in the formdesigner, in the lightning bolt of the properties grid after clicking the background of the form)

```
    (dataGridView1.DataSource as DataTable).WriteXml("grid.xml");
```

- Put this code in the FormLoad event

```
    var dt = new DataTable();
    if(File.Exists("grid.xml")){
      dt.ReadXml("grid.xml");
    } else {
      dt.Columns.Add("Name");
      dt.Columns.Add("Age");
    }
    dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
```